# Require multiple group membership in Google cloud resource permission

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

Is it possible to set up an access permission on GCP resource that requires multiple roles/permissions/groups membership? Basically, have a logical AND for permissions.

IAM "conditions" feature provides means for basic role assignment requirement, like time and duration restriction but this is not what I'm looking for.

Example organization structure:

```
- Testing folder:
 --- SomeProject     [Require "Testing" group membership]
 --- AnotherProject  [Require "Testing" group membership]
 --- SecretProject   [Require "Testing" AND "Secret" group membership]
 - Production folder
 --- SomeProject1    [Require "Production" group membership]
 --- AnotherProject1 [Require "Production" group mmebrship]
 --- SecretProject1  [Require "Production" AND "Secret" group membership]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hey as you mentioned [Cloud IAM Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-overview) does not fit on your need. I think [structuring organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy) can be one way to satisfy this requirement.

For example if we set as following and assigning permission on that folder level this cloud satisfies your needs.

```
                    ORG
                     |
      -------------------------------
     secret                      regular  (folders)
       |                           |
    --------                    --------
sec-      sec-               reg-     reg-  (Folders)
lab-1     lab-2              OP-1     OP-2
```

NOTE: I was meant to put this as a comment but due to my repulation putting this as an answer. However, if you suggest I will edit or change this answer.